# Gson error expected begin_object but was string at line 1 column 1 path $

Tags: java, android, json, gson

I hope you could give me a hand on a Gson issue I can't solve. It is quiet common apparently since I found many topic on this subject, but didn't manage to use answers.

I have this error :

> com.google.gson.JsonSyntaxException: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBjECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

Here is my Json :

```
{"valeurs":[{"Ident":"1","Lien":"r8WzdMerigo","Categorie":"1"},{"Ident":"2","Lien":"neqgJGz08Fw","Categorie":"2"}],"success":1}
```

Then my POJO:

```
public class gitmodel {


@SerializedName("Ident")
@Expose
private int Ident;

@SerializedName("Lien")
@Expose
private String Lien;

@SerializedName("Categorie")
@Expose
private int Categorie;




public int getIdent() {return Ident;}


public String getLien() {
    return Lien;
}



public int getCategorie() {
    return Categorie;
}
```

}

And finally in the Main activity :

```
RestAdapter restAdapter = new RestAdapter.Builder()
                    .setEndpoint(API)
                    .build();

            gitapi git = restAdapter.create(gitapi.class);


            git.getFeed("affichage_bd.php", new Callback<gitmodel>() {
                @Override
                public void success(gitmodel gitmodel, Response response) {
                    tv.setText("Numero categorie :" + gitmodel.getCategorie() + "\nLien :" + gitmodel.getLien() + "\nIdentification :" + gitmodel.getIdent());
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv.setText(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
        }
    });
```

Could you please tell me what's going on?

Answer (score 0):

You are missing a level. The POJO you set in Callback<> should be :

```
public class MyModel
{
  List<gitmodel> valeurs;

  public List<gitmodel> getValeurs()
   {
     return valeurs;
   }
}
```

**Edit:**
You should save the **MyModel** class somewhere in you project, and then change your interface to:

```
public interface gitapi {

   @GET("/users/{user}") 
   public void getFeed(@Path("user") String user, Callback<MyModel> myModel); 
}
```

So then in your **MainActivity**:

```
git.getFeed("affichage_bd.php", new Callback<MyModel>() {
                @Override
                public void success(MyModel myModel, Response response) {
                    List<gitmodel> valeurs = myModel.getValeurs();
                    //  here you can iterate through the elements on the list
                }

                @Override
                public void failure(RetrofitError error) {
                    tv.setText(error.getMessage());
                }
            });
```

Comment: Hi Kushtrim and thaks for your help !

However, I'm not sure to understand what to do ? 

My Callback is set in a interface : 

  public interface gitapi {
    @GET("/users/{user}")
    public void getFeed(@Path("user") String user, Callback<gitmodel> response);
}


Then where do I have to put MyModel instance ? Into the Main Activity ? I'm a bit lost sorry ....

Comment: Ok perfect thanks a lot for your edit :) !

However it seems that the error still occurs.I discovered I have a data error with my JSON. I tested it with http://jsonlint.com/ and same error  :     Expected BEGIN_OBjECT but was STRING at line 1 column 1 path $

I don't understand, I have a bracket in opening and closing ... ???!